# Android RadioGroup - will it work with additional components within?

Tags: android, radio-group

My idea is to have pairs ImageView - RadioButton, each pair enclosed in LinearLayout (horizontal orientation) and ImageButtons have their background color changed when an option is selected and confirmed. So, it would look like:

```
[LinearLayout1]: [ImageView1] [RadioButton1]
[LinearLayout2]: [ImageView2] [RadioButton2]
[LinearLayout3]: [ImageView3] [RadioButton3]
```

Is it possible to store this hierarchy within RadioGroup? I tried to apply this but see no ImageViews in my app. Or is RadioGroup built only for RadioButtons and all other views are ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  If it's not working, there's something else wrong with your code.

A proof of concept layout based on the ApiDemos sample Android app included in the SDK:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/lunch"
    android:id="@+id/menu">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_group_1_breakfast"
        android:id="@+id/breakfast"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_group_1_lunch"
            android:id="@id/lunch"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_group_1_dinner"
        android:id="@+id/dinner"/>


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_group_1_all"
        android:id="@+id/all"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_group_1_selection"
        android:id="@+id/choice"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

and the layout it produces:

[image: Radio buttons]

Comment: You're right, it can be done, thanks! Wasn't working in my case because of mix-up of XML-based and dynamically generated code, but eventually I made it.